# Can I use a USB webcam?

Tags: usb, peripherals, web-server, camera

Is it possible to use a standard USB webcam with the RPi, or is there a specific peripheral that should be used?

I would like to use RPi's to stream images from webcams to the net.

Comment: Keep in mind that webcams may be energy-hungry. My Pi resetted after a few seconds of recording (and skipped data) because it was connected directly on the USB port (i.e. no powered hub).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as the webcam is [Linux compatible](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/) it should be possible to get it to work.

However, if there are not ARM specific drivers available, you will have to build them yourself, which is often not easy.

Comment: @MattEllen Thanks for the heads up. I changed the link to guidance from the Ubuntu forums, which provides sources to extensive compatability lists.

Answer (score 13):

Raspberry Pi Foundation is also planning to make a camera module available at some point in the future. You can see a prototype at: http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1254.

This camera will connect via the CSI port - which means it will have the added advantage of not using up a USB port

So in summary, use a linux friendly camera with arm drivers for now - but prepare to upgrade to CSI cameras in future.