# How can I find out if my webcam is compatible?

Tags: peripherals, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use a USB webcam?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/714/can-i-use-a-usb-webcam)

Is there an official or other list of webcams that have been tested on the RPi?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a list of verified peripherals (and those with issues) available [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals).

You don't mention the distribution you are using nor the webcam brand/model but since the RPi is so new your particular combination may not have been tried yet.

You may want to do a Google search to see if anyone has gotten your cam to work with the x86 build of Debian or Arch, as this should give you a place to start.

If you try a peripheral that's not listed, don't forget to add it at the wiki link above.

Comment: I deliberately avoided adding my webcam to make the question more general, that looks like the list I was after